# Change the limit of multicast groups to join for DatagramChannel?

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, nio

My `DatagramChannel` cannot join more then 20 multicast groups. It throws the `java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available` exception on 21th attempt.

My code:

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET);
channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, false);
channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 16);
channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true).bind(new InetSocketAddress(50051));
channel.configureBlocking(false);
            
NetworkInterface ni = getNetworkInterface("my_ni");
    
for (int i = 1; i < 200; i+=2) {
     InetAddress groupToListen = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.x." + i);
     channel.join(groupToListen, ni);
     System.out.println("Joined: " + groupToListen.toString());
}
```

I tried to increase both send and receive buffers:

```
channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_SNDBUF, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

but it didn't help. Yes, I see that the buffers size has been increased **but the number of groups I was able to join remained the same**.

The limitation applies per process, so if I start 10 instances of the above test app, giving it no more then 20 groups to join, it will be OK in each case.

Any suggestion how I can increase this limit ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone needs this in future:

It was the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/igmp_max_memberships` tunable.
I had a default value of 20 - exactly matches the number of groups I was able to join.

Increasing this parameter solved the issue.